# How can function call another functions in same class python

Tags: python

I want to create a class that includes some functions, that one of them call another one in class, something like that:

```
import pandas as pd


class Prep:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def slicing(self):
        sliceInput = self.data.iloc[:, 1:8]
        sliceTarget = self.data.iloc[:, 8]
        return sliceInput, sliceTarget

    def convert(self):
        convertInput = sliceInput.to_numpy(float)
        convertTarget = sliceTarget.to_numpy(int)
        return convertInput, convertTarget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_frame = pd.read_csv('data_manual.csv', sep=';')

    tes = Prep(data_frame)
    print(tes.convert())
```

i got error like this
`NameError: name 'sliceInput' is not defined`

how to call `convertInput` and `convertTarget` in function
why I get an error, I don't understand at all.

Comment: may be `self.sliceInput = self.data.iloc[:, 1:8]`  and `self.sliceTarget = self.data.iloc[:, 8]` will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `sliceInput, sliceTarget = self.slicing()` in `covert`

```
import pandas as pd


class Prep:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def slicing(self):
        sliceInput = self.data.iloc[:, 1:8]
        sliceTarget = self.data.iloc[:, 8]

        return sliceInput, sliceTarget

    def convert(self):
        sliceInput, sliceTarget = self.slicing()
        convertInput = sliceInput.to_numpy(float)
        convertTarget = sliceTarget.to_numpy(int)
        return convertInput, convertTarget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_frame = pd.read_csv('data_manual.csv', sep=';')

    tes = Prep(data_frame)
    print(tes.convert())
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `self` to the defined attributes.
Also, because `data` is immutable after you have instantiated a `Prep` object, it would be better for performance if you just initialize the slice variables once in the `__init__()` method.

```py
import pandas as pd


class Prep:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.sliceInput = data.iloc[:, 1:8]
        self.sliceTarget = data.iloc[:, 8]

    def slicing(self):
        return self.sliceInput, self.sliceTarget


    def convert(self):
        convertInput = self.sliceInput.to_numpy(float)
        convertTarget = self.sliceTarget.to_numpy(int)
        return convertInput, convertTarget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_frame = pd.read_csv('data_manual.csv', sep=';')

    tes = Prep(data_frame)
    print(tes.convert())
```